# pointwise/uniform convergence of these sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $$A = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid  |x| \leq 1/2 \ \text{or} \ |x|
> \geq 2 \right\}. $$ Determine the convergence (pointwise/uniform) of
>   the function $$f_n : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto
> \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}. $$

I think the limit of these functions is $$f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if} \ |x| \leq 1/2 \\ 1 & |x| \geq 2 \end{cases}. $$

But I'm not sure if this is pointwise or uniform convergence, and how to prove it. I don't think it is uniform convergence, since $$ \sup_{x \geq 2} \big| \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} - 1 \big| = \sup_{x \geq 2} \big| \frac{1}{1+x^n}  \big| \not \rightarrow 0.$$

Answer (score 2):

As you have already remarked, for $|x| \geq 2$, we only have to consider 
$\sup_{x\geq 2} \left|\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right|$.

We calculate
$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right| \geq \left|\frac{1}{1+(x+\epsilon)^n}\right|$, for any $\epsilon, x > 0$ or (or $\epsilon < 0$ and $x<0$). Thus

$\sup_{x\geq 2} \left|\frac{1}{1+x^n}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{1+2^n}\right| \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$

For $|x| \leq 0.5$, note that $\frac{a+c}{b+c} \geq \frac{a}{b}$, if all $a,b$ and $c$ are positive. A similar statement holds for negative numbers. With that, we calculate

$\sup_{|x|\leq \frac{1}{2}} \left|\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\right| \leq \left|\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^n}{1+(\frac{1}{2})^n}\right| = \frac{1}{2^n+1} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$.

So the convergence is uniform.

Comment: So the my limit function was correct? Convergence is to $1$ if $|x| \geq 2$ and $0$ if $|x| \leq 1/2$ ?

Comment: Yes, your limits are correct.

Comment: Is it also possible to prove uniform convergence with $\epsilon - n_0$ definition? Because then we would need to find a $n_0$ that works for both cases.